# 3x3 matrix conversion without loop (RGB color conversion)

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy

I have an RGB image loaded into a numpy array via PIL. I get a rows x cols x 3 array. After tinkering, I arrived at the following code. I'd like to learn how to do such an array/matrix manipulation without the loop.

```
# Note using matrix not array.
rgb_to_ycc = np.matrix(
     (0.2990,  0.5870,  0.1140,
    -0.1687, -0.3313,  0.5000,
     0.5000, -0.4187, -0.0813,)
).reshape( 3,3 )

ycc_to_rgb = np.matrix(
    ( 1.0, 0.0, 1.4022,
      1.0, -0.3456, -0.7145,
      1.0, 1.7710, 0, )
).reshape( 3, 3 )

def convert_ycc_to_rgb( ycc ) :
    # convert back to RGB
    rgb = np.zeros_like( ycc )
    for row in range(ycc.shape[0]) :
        rgb[row] = ycc[row] * ycc_to_rgb.T
    return rgb

def convert_rgb_to_ycc( rgb ) :
    ycc = np.zeros_like( rgb )
    for row in range(rgb.shape[0]):
        ycc[row] = rgb[row] * rgb_to_ycc.T
    return ycc
```

I could use http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colormath (via [Using Python to convert color formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119754/using-python-to-convert-color-formats)) but I'm using this as an exercise to learn numpy.

The aforementioned Colormath library uses a dot product.

```
# Perform the adaptation via matrix multiplication.
result_matrix = numpy.dot(var_matrix, rgb_matrix)
```

My math isn't where it should be. Is np.dot() my best bet?

EDIT. After deeper reading colormath's apply_RGB_matrix()-color_conversions.py, I found the np.dot() works if my conversion 3x3s are *not* matrices. Weird.

```
def convert_rgb_to_ycc( rgb ) :
    return np.dot( rgb, np.asarray( rgb_to_ycc ).T )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about the formula you are using to [convert RGB to YCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr), so I don't want to claim this is the complete calculation, but to simplify the function you posted, yes, use `np.dot` with numpy arrays instead of numpy matrices.

`np.dot` is more general than `*` with numpy matrices. When using `*` with numpy matrices, the two matrices have to be 2 dimensional. 
But `np.dot` can produce a result with arrays of different shape. This is important for your application since `rgb` is 3-dimensional (e.g. when it has shape (1470, 2105, 3)).

The docs for `np.dot` say:

```
    For N dimensions it is a sum product over the last axis of `a` and
    the second-to-last of `b`::

        dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])
```

This is a generalization of regular matrix multiplication.

---

I suggest calling your ultimate function `rgb_to_ycc`, instead of giving that designation to the constant matrix. (It's shorter and says exactly what you want the function to do.)

So below, `rgb_to_ycc` is my suggested function, and I made some minor modifications to make `convert_rgb_to_ycc` not raise exceptions and do the computation I think you are intending.

The final line, `np.allclose(...)` shows the two functions return the same result.

```
import numpy as np

def rgb_to_ycc(rgb):
    M = np.array(
         (0.2990,  0.5870,  0.1140,
        -0.1687, -0.3313,  0.5000,
         0.5000, -0.4187, -0.0813,)
        ).reshape( 3,3 )
    return np.dot(rgb, M.T)

def convert_rgb_to_ycc( rgb ) :
    M = np.matrix(
         (0.2990,  0.5870,  0.1140,
        -0.1687, -0.3313,  0.5000,
         0.5000, -0.4187, -0.0813,)
        ).reshape( 3,3 )
    shape=rgb.shape
    rgb=rgb.reshape((-1,3))
    ycc = np.zeros_like( rgb )
    for i in range(len(rgb)):
        ycc[i] = rgb[i] * M.T
    return ycc.reshape(shape)

rgb=np.random.random((100,100,3))
assert np.allclose(rgb_to_ycc(rgb),convert_rgb_to_ycc(rgb))
```

Comment: Ah! Using the 3x3 as array instead of matrix was indeed the solution. And inlining the conversion matrices does make for better looking code. Thanks! And np.allclose() is something new to learn.

Answer (score 3):

```
def convert_ycc_to_rgb(ycc):
    return ycc * ycc_to_rgb.T

def convert_rgb_to_ycc(rgb):
    return rgb * rgb_to_ycc.T
```

as simple as that, remember how matrix multiplication is defined in terms of inner products of rows and columns.

**edit:**

I was assuming that the rgb and ycc matrices were just a matrix that had as many rows as pixels and a column per colour component. So what we need to do first is to reshape them to a `(rows*cols,3)` and then back again to `(rows, cols, 3)`.

So the code finally is:

```
def convert_ycc_to_rgb(ycc):
    shape = ycc.shape
    return np.array(ycc.reshape(-1,3) * ycc_to_rgb.T).reshape(shape)

def convert_rgb_to_ycc(rgb):
    shape = rgb.shape
    return np.array(rgb.reshape(-1,3) * rgb_to_ycc.T).reshape(shape)
```

Comment: I originally tried that. rgb.shape is, say, (1470, 2105, 3). rgb_to_ycc is (3,3).  ValueError: shape too large to be a matrix.

Comment: oh, I see, I was thinking about serialized pixel colours... let me hack it a little bit ;-)